# Правильная переадресация (header redirect) и смена языка на сайте

Tags: php, redirect, header

Есть у меня самописный роутер на php. Он разбивает `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` на части. Дальше у меня есть несколько методов, которые проверяют необходимые условия:

**Первый**

```
function getModule() {
    $allowedModule = ['web_site', 'control_panel'];
    $module        = NULL;

    $uri = $this->URI;

    if (isset($uri[0])) {
        if ($uri[0] == 'admin')
            $module = $allowedModule[1];
        else
            $module = $allowedModule[0];
    } else
        $module = $allowedModule[0];

    $this->URL['module'] = $module;

    return $module;
}
```

Он проверяет раздел сайта который надо подключить, то есть модуль `control_panel` это есть административная панель.
А модуль `web_site` это есть сам сайт который видет посетитель.

**Второй**  Дальше у меня идет:

```
function getLocale() {
    $allowedLocale = ['ua', 'en', 'pl'];
    $defaultLocale = $allowedLocale[0];
    $module        = $this->MODULE;
    $locale        = $defaultLocale;

    if ($module == 'web_site') {
        if (isset($this->URI[0])) {
            if (in_array($this->URI[0], $allowedLocale, true)) {
                $locale = Validate::strLength(Validate::string($this->URI[0]), 2);
            } else {
                $locale = $defaultLocale;
            }

        }
    } elseif ($module == 'control_panel') {
        if (isset($this->URI[1])) {
            if (in_array($this->URI[1], $allowedLocale, true)) {
                $locale = Validate::strLength(Validate::string($this->URI[1]), 2);
            } else {
                $locale = $defaultLocale;
            }
        }
    }

    $this->URL['locale'] = $locale;

    return $locale;
}
```

Этот метод отвечает за мультиязычность на сайте. В административной панели нету мультиязычности, только на самом веб-сайте.

**Третий**

```
function getTemplate() {

    $module          = $this->MODULE;
    $locale          = $this->LANG;
    $defaultTemplate = 'main';

    if ($module == 'control_panel') {
        if (isset($this->URI[1])){
            $templateFile = $this->URI[1];
            if(isset($this->URI[2])){
                $this->URL['params'] = $this->URI[2];
            }
        } else{
            $templateFile = $defaultTemplate;
        }
    } else {
        if ($locale == 'ua') {
            if (isset($this->URI[0])){
                $templateFile = $this->URI[0];
                if(isset($this->URI[1])){
                    $this->URL['params'] = $this->URI[1];
                }
            }
            else{
                $templateFile = $defaultTemplate;
            }
        } else {
            if (isset($this->URI[1]))
                $templateFile = $this->URI[1];
            else
                $templateFile = $defaultTemplate;
        }
    }

    $templatePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/application/views/' . $module . '/';
    if (file_exists($templatePath . '/' . $templateFile . '.php')) {
        $template = $templateFile;
    } else {
        $template = 'error';
    }

    $this->URL['template'] = $template;

    return $template;
}

function getParams() {
    return $this->URL['params'];
}
```

Отвечает за подключаемый шаблон. Знаю, роутер не должен этого делать, но пока что у меня такая система, со временем я научусь и разберусь с правильными роутерами.

**Мне нужно:**

У меня всё работает. Но! Я хочу сделать метод переадресации, и не знаю как правильно его написать.

У меня есть обычная ф-ция (вне этого класса роутера), которая добавляет слеш в конце url. По такому примеру пытаюсь сделать нужный мне метод, но пока безуспешно.

```
$exp = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (mb_substr($exp[0], -1) != '/') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $exp[0] . '/' . (!empty($exp[1]) ? '?' . $exp[1] : ''));
    exit();
}
```

Нужный мне метод и пример:

```
function Run(){
        // помогите :)
    }
```

Мне нужна переадресация следующего образа. Например, пользователь вводит:

`http://web-site.com/` переадресация должна быть на `http://web-site.com/ua/`, или
`http://web-site.com/catalog/` должно переадресовать на `http://web-site.com/ua/catalog/`

Теперь еще один вопрос по поводу смены языка. Как мне лучше всего это сделать?
Пока что у меня это происходит так:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/ua/">УКР</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en/">ENG</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pl/">PL</a></li>
</ul>
```

Но, если посетитель находится например в `http://web-site.com/ua/catalog/` то его перекинет на главную страницу. Посоветуйте решение, пожалуйста.
Спасибо заранее